# Linux make shows that 'SIGPIPE' has not been declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, cmake

When I use the make command, it prompts the following statement.

```
main. cpp: 10:9: Error: 'SIGPIPE' has not been declared in this scope
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
       ^
main. cpp: 10:18: Error: 'SIG_ IGN 'has not been declared in this scope
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
                ^
main. cpp: 10:25: Error: 'signal 'has not been declared in this scope
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
                       ^
```

This is the code for main.cpp.

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    return 0;
}
```

So what causes this problem?

Comment: That error message does not seem to correspond exactly to the source code you have shown. Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Yes, there are three lines of commented ToDo statements above. I deleted them, which leads to mismatched line numbers. I will modify them.

Comment: What is Linux make? Do you run it on Windows?

Comment: I used Visual Studio to remotely connect to Linux development, which automatically generated output files. When I try to compile on Linux using CMake, it prompts me for an error, but there is no error when running on vs.

Also, when I run on vs, it doesn't need # include<iostream>to use string, but when I use CMake, it still prompts an error: string is not declared.

Comment: You can remove everything log and server related for the demonstration.

Comment: You could even remove cmake from the whole picture to get closer to a [mcve]. Also, the error message seems to be about `Main. cpp` and `main. cpp` while you mention `main.cpp` later. Those are three different filenames.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question again.

Comment: Standard header `signal.h` definitely contains declaration of `signal` function and definition of macros SIGPIPE and SIG_IGN. Probably, something wrong in your environment setup that a compiler finds another header `signal.h`. You question post contains none information about your environment, so we cannot help you. For debug, you could create preprocessed version of your source file (by using `-E` option for compiler instead of `-c`). In the preprocessed file look for exact path of `signal.h` header and look for preprocessed content of it.

Comment: "I used Visual Studio to remotely connect to Linux development," I don't understand this sentence. remotely connect to a Linux machine? Or are you developing on WSL, which is usually what Microsoft refers to when talking about "Linux development".

Comment: @MilanŠ. To be precise, SSH is used to connect my virtual machine remotely.

Comment: @wblxwz can you switch `#include <signal.h>` with `#include <csignal>` ? This is the header I frequently use for signals in C++ projects

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I found the reason, and repeated naming led to the problem. But # include "signal. h" and # include<signal. h>look different, don't they?